# Integrating Webcam with OpenCV and OpenGL using C++ in Ubuntu?

Tags: c++, opencv, opengl, terminal, ubuntu-18.04

I'm trying to capture image from a webcam following tutorial from this book : [Building Computer Vision Projects with OpenCV 4 and C++ (2019)](https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/building-computer-vision-projects-opencv-4-and-c). I've updated severeal code following [OpenCV 4.2.0 documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.2.0/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html) to use `VideoCapture` for capturing. For the sake of simplicity, I'm gonna put only code related to calling the camera here :

```
#include "opencv2/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/videoio.hpp"

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <GL/glut.h>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

Mat frame;
GLfloat angle = 0.0;
GLuint texture;
VideoCapture camera;

int main(int argc, const char** argv){
    int deviceID = 2;  
    int apiID = 0;
    camera.open(deviceID + apiID);

    if (!camera.isOpened())
        {
            cout << "ERROR : Can't open camera" << endl;
            return -1;
        }

    namedWindow("OpenGL Camera", WINDOW_OPENGL); 
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    setOpenGlDrawCallback("OpenGL Camera", on_opengl);

    while(waitKey(30) !='q'){
        camera >> frame;
        loadTexture();
        updateWindow("OpenGL Camera");
        angle = angle+4;
    }

    destroyWindow("OpenGL Camera");
    return 0;
}
```

Here's the [full code in gist](https://gist.github.com/nowhere-girl/e6e4df607f361f3f9192f264ff7372d0). I encountered this error :

```
[ WARN:0] global /home/raisa/Documents/OpenCV/opencv-4.2.0_source/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (935) open OpenCV | GStreamer warning: Cannot query video position: status=0, value=-1, duration=-1
```

I'm using Camera 2 (external webcam - Logitech C930e), that is tested before and is working fine on Ubuntu. I've set it as default camera as well for **guvcview** and **Cheese** with  no problem. But even when I tried with Camera 0 (integrated webcam), I still encounter exactly the same issue that lead me to believe it's not camera issue, but coding issue.

I came across this question : [Capturing 1080p at 30fps from Logitech C920 with openCV 2.4.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16092802/capturing-1080p-at-30fps-from-logitech-c920-with-opencv-2-4-3) which using a Logitech camera as well but using very old version of OpenCV (2.4.3), anyway I tried to implement his/her approach by using this :

```
camera.open(2, CAP_DSHOW);
camera.set(CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1920);
camera.set(CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 1080);
```

There's no error output but I only get black screen. I thought maybe it needed more time to load, so I also tried to increase `waitKey` to `waitKey(300)`, but still black screen.

There's also the same problem here : [Display a image from the Webcam using openCV and openGL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28011692/display-a-image-from-the-webcam-using-opencv-and-opengl), but it's using Modern OpenGL which I don't use at the moment since I'm following a specific tutorial from a book. If this information helps I'm compiling with CMake in terminal Ubuntu, what I have installed on my machine :

```
Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
OpenCV version : 4.2.0
OpenGL version : 4.6 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 20.1.0-devel 
Cmake version  : 3.10.2
```

Any advice ?

Comment: Maybe a stupid question (I don't normally use opengl directly), but I don't see where exactly you update the window that is supposed to show the captured frame. `camera >> frame;` <-- OK, but then what do you do with the frame?

Comment: My guess is that this is not related to OpenGL. Get rid of OpenGL in your code and make sure you have a minimal complete application that retrieves frames from the camera and displays them in a window using OpenCV. After that we can talk further.

Comment: @pptaszni I don't put the full code, but I've updated my question and added gist link to the full code. Basically the frame captured is going to be rotated and displayed in a window with OpenGL support. It's just a simple program to rotate frame.